# How to compile native library for armv8?

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I am compiling split apk's for four architectures x86,x86_64,armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a. The app is working fine and loading native libraries fine on majority of devices.  but on some devices The error occurs that unable to find mylibrary.so .in armv8 folder or in arm folder. here is my code to generate split apk's and genertes Unsatisfied Link Error

```
splits {
        // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
        abi {
            // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
            enable true


            // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
            // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
            reset()

            // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
            include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

            // Specifies that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
            universalApk false
        }
    }



    def abiCodes = ['x86':0, 'x86_64':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // Assigns a different version code for each output APK.
        variant.outputs.each {
            output ->
                def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                output.versionCodeOverride = abiCodes.get(abiName, 0) + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
```

when i analyze apk i succesfully get required native libs in arm64-v8a apk
 in libs folder and in libs folder of all other apk's.

Comment: what is the complete error log?

Comment: it is runtime error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Comment: Could you be more specific? Which library is it not finding? Yours, or a dependency? Do you depend on a third-party library that is not available for arm64?

Comment: @DanAlbert Albert I am compiling open cv android sdk .so files and also i have my own .so file. the devices that pick binary libraries from arm64 are working good. but some devices seems to pick binary files from armv8 and i causes crash. i am compiling arm64-v8a architecture. I think devices with armv8 should pick binary from arm64-v8a or arm64

Comment: But what is the error? The actual error message.

Comment: @DanAlbert these are error msgs . Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.whizpool.ezywatermarklite-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.package.myapp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:377)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)

Comment: That looks like the opposite of the problem you described. It can't find the 32-bit ARM libraries.

Comment: @DanAlbert how can i solve this issue. the same error comes with armv8. i mean this line 1/lib/arm is replaced with 1/lib/armv8 on some devices